# Pass row id when clicking button in report

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have a report that I have included a button to the detail area of the report, so every row has a button.  The button's On Click is set to btnCheck_Click().  How do I get the Id field of that row to my VBA function?  From there it does some sanity checking and then re-queries the form to refresh it.  But I need to pass it that ID.  So on a page of 100 records I have 100 id's, how do I reference the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your ID field is either bound to a control on the form, or at least defined in the recordset if not bound, or if you mean the current RECORD NUMBER, the following will work:

```
Private Sub btnCheck_Click()
    MsgBox Me.ID & vbTab & Me!ID & vbtab & CurrentRecord   ' Bound Field Content  |  Unbound Field  |  Current Record
End Sub
```